# Help interpreting image prediction

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, scikit-learn, image-processing

Could someone tell me why my predicted result ("Predicted Heatmap") has "ghost layers" and gray background? What can I do to improve my model?

**What I've done to the images **

- normalized pixel values from (0,255) to (0,1)
- reshaped image size from (128,128,3) to (49152)
- redid it all and ran array results into array_to_img to get it back into image form

[image]

Comment: This is a visual representation of regression to the mean.

Comment: So the results are due to chance? Is there a way to confirm this numerically?

Comment: It often happens when changing data into a limited number of shades of gray that the image degrades by forming plateaus that do not render the contrast properly. For example, if one starts with 256 shades, it can turn into 16 shades and disrupts proper visualization. If one starts with real numbers, one should do the image rendering into shades of gray as the last possible step. Frankly, I don't know that the problem you are having is due to that because you haven't provided enough information. But something like that seems to be in the images.

Comment: No, the results are not due to chance: that is not what regression to the mean is.  This phenomenon occurs even when chance is not involved.  The best predictions tend to be closer to the mean and not to reproduce the full variability of the original response.  As the [Encyclopedia Britannica asserts](https://www.britannica.com/topic/regression-to-the-mean), "Given a less than perfect correlation between [any two variables, such as a response and its prediction], RTM is a mathematical necessity."  cc@Carl

Comment: What model/approach do you suggest using to improve the prediction? This is the overall problem I'm trying to solve: given an input 3D scan of a foot, predict an orthotic shell